# python parent directory

Tags: python, directory, parent

I want to get the parent directory of a file.
This code doesn't work:

```
projectRoot = os.path.dirname(os.pardir(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

What's wrong?

(I am developing a django application, and use this variable in the settings file of my application)

Thanks.

Romain

Comment: Check out the UniPath module, this helps with this problem excellently.

Comment: `os.pardir` is not what you think it is: `>>> os.pardir`
`'..'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the parent directory by using `..`

```
import os
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir)
```

OR:

```
import os
split_limit = 1 if os.path.isdir(__file__) else 0
parent_dir = os.path.abspath(__file__).rsplit(os.path.sep, split_limit)[0]
```

Comment: I used your first solution, works well! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As simple as this:

```
import os
def get_parent_dir(file_path):
    return os.path.dirname(file_path)
```

To get the file_path of the script being run, you could do this:

```
import sys
file_path = sys.argv[0]
```

Comment: `os.path.dirname` appears to return the absolute *path* to the file, not the *name* of the file's immediate parent directory

Answer (score 0):

in our django project we use next structure:
we have prodaction_settings.py  where placed settings for prodaction server and all variables. on local machine in file settings.py

```
from os.path import dirname, abspath, join
TEST_DIR = dirname(abspath(__file__))
from production_settings import *
```

to add your local folder with templates:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    join(TEST_DIR, 'tmpl'), 
)
```